# REQ: Retrieving properties in my java app. collected by "PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" -- properties are stored in a database as key/value

Tags: java, spring

PUsing Spring 3.2.0.release and JDK 1.6. I've a standalone Java program (NOT running inside tomcat etal) and I'm loading properties from a database.

I've used this excellent article as a base and it works perfectly. Using the `PropertiesPrinter` bean (defined there) as a base and adding `getters` I can do stuff like `getFileLocation()`, `getPetDogsName()` but then I need to have/create `setter/getters` for every property.

What I would like to have is a Spring Bean or normal Java class called DatabaseProperties with a method like `getProperty("filelocation")`; which I can use in my application (main)and so I can retrieve/get the value of the property filelocation which is somewhere inside the information collected by `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`.

I've done a lot of digging but can't seem to find the information I need or at least I'm not able to combine the gathered info into a working program as I'm not fluent with Spring....

Any hint/pointers/urls/code is higly appreciated. It's probably relative easy but it is still out of reach for me atm.

Answer (score 1):

One solution for reading values set by the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`, is to use the [@Value](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html) annotation rather than a method for setting class member variables:

```
class MyClass {

   @Value("${file.location}")
   private String fileLocation;
   ...
}
```